# $ \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \ \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_{ij} \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \ \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} x_{ij} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

It's well known that the sum of the limits is the limit of the sum, if the limits exist. I mean $$ \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}   \ \sum_{i=1}^k   x_{ij}
=
  \sum_{i=1}^k \ \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}  x_{ij}.
  $$

Now let $x_{ij}$ be any none negative real sequence. Is the following inequality necessarily true?
$$ \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}   \ \sum_{i=1}^\infty   x_{ij}
\leq
  \sum_{i=1}^\infty \ \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}  x_{ij} 
  $$

If not, what would be a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite inequality is always correct:
$$\sum \limits_{i = 1}^\infty \liminf \limits_{j \to \infty} \; x_{i, j} \le \liminf \limits_{j \to \infty}\; \sum \limits_{i = 1}^\infty x_{i, j}$$

This is an application of [Fatou's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou's_lemma) to the counting measure.

If you want to see an example where strict inequality holds, consider $x_{i, j} = I\{i = j\}$. Then $x_{i, j} \xrightarrow{j \to \infty} 0$, but $\sum \limits_{i = 1}^\infty x_{i, j} = 1$.